# Why is my .js file not running on my website?

Tags: javascript

Heyy, I'm doing a project for my Full-stack course and I want to make a dropdown menu for the mobile view, but for some reason my .js file doesn't work, even though it is exactly as seen in the tutorials and websites that I have seen to do this.

I already tried to do it with Bootstrap as well but the same thing happened, everything works perfect until the moment of applying the mobile view and the menu does not display.

More exactly, when I switch my website to mobile view, it adapts as I want, but when clicking on the drop-down menu icon nothing is displayed, no menu appears anywhere.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mediaqueries.css">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href='https://css.gg/menu.css' rel='stylesheet'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
         integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
         crossorigin="anonymous" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Información</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
         <div class="menu-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
         </div>
      </header>
      <!-- INICIO DEL HEADER -->
      <div class="header">
         <h1 class="title">DevHub - A Developer Matchmaking .</h1>
         <p class="description">CREA Y COMPARTE TUS IDEAS, ENCUENTRA COMPAÑEROS Y COMIENZA z DESARROLLAR</p>
      </div>
      <!-- FIN DEL HEADER -->
      <!-- SEGUNDA SECCIÓN -->
      <div class="section1">
         <a href="#" class="section1-perfil">
            <h2>Crea tu perfil</h2>
            <p class="profile-description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum odio est
               ducimus dignissimos necessitatibus minus modi molestias hic! Quam, ex? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
               consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione nobis esse incidunt aut ad itaque voluptatibus eligendi iste non
               voluptatem.
            </p>
         </a>
         <a href="#" class="section1-proyectos">
            <h3>Proyectos populares</h3>
            <p class="profile-description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum odio est
               ducimus dignissimos necessitatibus minus modi molestias hic! Quam, ex? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
               consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione nobis esse incidunt aut ad itaque voluptatibus eligendi iste non
               voluptatem.
            </p>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!-- FIN DE LA SEGUNDA SECCIÓN -->
      <script src="menu.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

and my .js file:

```js
let menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-Toggle');
let menuToggleIcon = document.querySelector('.menu-Toggle i');
let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    
menuToggle.addEventListener('click', e => {
    menu.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

Comment: A) Explain "doesn't work" in more technical terms. B) If this is a JavaScript question the CSS is completely irrelevant and should be removed.

Comment: You have a typo in your querySelector. The class is called menu-toggle, not menu-Toggle.

Comment: Tadman: already edited the question but I'll put it here too: when I switch my website to mobile view, it adapts as I want, but when clicking on the drop-down menu icon nothing is displayed, no menu appears anywhere.

Patrick: just tried that and the problem is still happening :/

Comment: did u find the answer? If not, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/340pq98k/32/. I have just edited your js code. hope it helps you. Also, to make sure your script path is correct please add a console log inside your event listener. If it doesn't fire then the path to the JS file might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality of some dropdowns are dependent to jQuery file. Try to include jQuery in your project.

To make sure you have included your .js file correctly, open your page on browser, press Ctrl and U button at the same time to open the source view. You will see the files you've included. Click on your file. If the file opened correctly, you're good. Otherwise it will say file not found. In this case you should link your .js file correctly.

Place your script page and .js files at the same folder/directory.

Comment: Included jquery file in my project and I checked if the .js file loaded fine and yup, problem still happening.

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, so make sure there is no any spelling difference or mis capitalization. menu-Toggle > menu-toggle

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are using "toggle" in with the capital T and it should be all lowercase as it says in your HTML, try this:

```js
let menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
let menuToggleIcon = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle i');
let menu = document.getElementById('menu');

menuToggle.addEventListener('click',e=>{
    menu.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

The other thing that may be is that the CSS of ID `# menu` is conflicting and it does not make the `.show` class work, look at this example without there being styles in the id but a class that hides: https://jsfiddle.net/y42gaLq3/3/

Comment: Made some changes to the CSS file and also changed every .menu-Toggle to lowercase and still doesnt work, I'm starting to think it's my computer's problem. I just sent the files to a friend to see if it works for him.

Comment: Another very common problem, if you are working locally may be the "cache", try to open the project in "incognito" in the browser to see if it works there after your change. The real way to help you is by viewing the files if you manage to upload it to a storage with pleasure I review it.

Comment: Still not working after opening the project in incognito mode, all cache was cleared and nothing. My friend opened it from his computer and it doesn't work for him either, I really don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Try uploading it to Google Drive or other storage service and share it in "public" so I can see what happens to the whole project and see if I can find the answer.